# I have a Batch file that runs perfectly fine on a local machine, but doesn't run through SCCM

Tags: windows, batch-file, sccm

```
@echo off

taskkill /IM Notebook.exe /F

taskkill /IM ResponseSoftwareService.exe /F

taskkill /IM DesktopMenu.exe /F

del "C:\ProgramData\FLEXNet\*" /A /Q /F

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\SMART Technologies\SMART Product Update\activationwizard.exe" --puid education_bundle --m=4 --v=3 --a --pk="Key input here"
```

This is the code I placed the actual key where it says *Key input here*....But like I said when I run this batch file locally everything runs correctly. but when I put it in the Task sequence of SCCM it doesn't run correctly and I have to run this batch file any way. Any ideas or tips?

Comment: Probably permissions.  What user does SCCM run the batch file as?

Answer (score 0):

What return code do you get?

It might also be worth redirecting the output of each command and its exit code to get more information, so for example:

```
taskkill /IM Notebook.exe /F >> C:\Windows\Temp\mylogfile.log
echo %ERRORLEVEL% >> C:\Windows\Temp\mylogfile.log

taskkill /IM ResponseSoftwareService.exe /F >> C:\Windows\Temp\mylogfile.log
echo %ERRORLEVEL% >> C:\Windows\Temp\mylogfile.log
```

And so on.

That should then tell you if it's permissions related or any other errors that arise.

If you're stilling having problems afterwards then post your results and I'll be happy to advise further.